# Create vs Edit mode in a web form

Tags: standards, webforms

I am creating a web form where people are asked to fill in their work time daily. Since it's a daily task, I'm providing the option to set default values in the user settings. This could make it unclear to users whether they have already saved the day's values. They should also be able to edit days they have already saved, all within the same form.

What is the best way to display the different statuses from a UX perspective?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to fill the default values because:

- it will create confusion as you have mentioned that it will give if this is my saved data
- if they want new data to type then they have to erase and type it, make it more annoying

The simple solution would be just give the intelligence when they type by showing the recent data they have typed before.  From there they can select previous data or type new data.

Hope this will help

Comment: I agree on the confusion. If a suggest/type ahead system isn't feasible, then what about a "fill from template" button. This would add "favorite" data to the form and since its based on a user action wouldn't be as confusing about what's "done".

Answer (score 0):

from my experience the best way to do this is

- to block the fields that are already saved and to add an edit `button` to unblock the fields, when the edit `button` is pressed you can change the text to save and save the data that has been changed
- you can add an `i` icon to let the user know that this field is using the default settings from his profile

please check this example that I found on google this will explain a lot
[image]